# Mixing colours to create a gold shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am looking at how to create a realistic looking gold material (for instance for ingots). I found this [gold material](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/38983) at blend swap.

[image]

The shader uses a mix of colours (mixing forecolor and middle color and then mixing again with a back color). Can someone explain this? Why this mixing of colors? How does this work ?

Comment: @cegaton yes I did write him a Facebook message but he did not react

Comment: can you write a personal message on blender artists.org or only forum posts ?

Comment: @Elbrujodelatribu can you answer this one?

Comment: I would completely rebuild this from scratch incorporating PBR concepts. See [CynicatPro's YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/CynicatPro) - all the videos pertaining to Physically-Based Shading.

Comment: sorry, I answered to Jan before see this question here ;) I did a render about ingots with Colombia Gold material. You can see it on http://elbrujodelatribu.deviantart.com/art/Blender-Cycles-Gold-Ingots-348943728 (you can find some info about it in its description and commets)

Comment: @JanScherders please write an answer (we have way too many unanswered questions already)

Comment: @Elbrujodelatribu thanks for your answer on Facebook (where you explain that your shader is the result of many tests). But I still would like to understand why your shader uses a mix of colours (mixing forecolor and middle color and then mixing again with a back color). And maybe you can explain why you did chose these specific colours ?

Comment: Ok, I will answer this. I'm going to prepare it properly.

Comment: @Mentalist hi, following up your suggestion I invested quite some time to watch the Physically-Based Shading videos and tried to rebuild some shaders based on those tutorials. However, as these tutorials are quite challenging for me as a beginner I would like to have some feedback and ask some questions about these shaders. Is Blender.Stackexchange the right place for that ? And is CynicatPro maybe a Stackexchange member ?

Comment: @JanScherders What I would do is leave a comment on CynicatPro's channel inviting him over here to join the discussion. Then we can have a big geek-out over physically-based shaders. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I create a Cycles material I make this process:

1) I take real references. When I make a material I pretend it to be realistic, since Cycles is a physically based render engine. In this case I took these references:

[image]

1. Tutankhamun mask (Egypt Gold?)
2. Yotoco pectoral (Colombia Gold?)
3. Some gold ingots
4. An ancient coin

You can notice that there are many types of gold materials.

2) I try to find the correct mix of diffuse-glossy-SSS-transparent-etc shaders, making several tests. This was the second material I published in Blend Swap, so I had little experience in Cycles. So I made more than 100 tests. It is very important that you use a good test scene ([Tuqueque's Blender Ball](http://download.blender.org/demo/test/Demo_274.zip) or others)

[image]

3) Finally I tune or adjust some details, for example **colors** or textures. In my first attempt I use a **color picker**. A color picker is a tool which catches the RGB components of a pixel in my reference image. You can use any photo edition software. I use Firefox and its [Rainbow addon](http://harthur.github.com/rainbow). Then I make more tests. Depending on my results I pick other pixels or use the blender color wheel to adjust the colors.

Here I show you the Rainbow addon catching a RGB color pointed by the mouse cursor:

[image]
[image]

TIP: A real material,like gold, has many hues. You can not make it mixing only a diffuse color and a glossy color. I recommend you use several colors and use *Fresnel* or *Facing* factors to mix them properly in a physically correct way.

NOTE: I am very proud of this set of gold materials. I used the same nodes to create the copper material. I only changed the colors. It is available in [Blend Swap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/69793).

Comment: I really appreciate it that you want to share the concepts and ideas behind your Gold Shader !! Thanks a lot !!