# Any help with that material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm trying to make my material look like this

[image]

I played with nodes but couldn't come up with anything resembling the yellow material in picture.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40565/mixing-colours-to-create-a-gold-shader ?

Comment: Material appearance is the result the interaction of multiple factor such as the light, the environment, how the object is modeled and, finally, the shader itself. Could you show what you have done so far to get an idea of where exacty you are stuck?